# Reordering UITableView without Using UITableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

So this is what I have (simplified):

```
 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 10;
    }

    -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            cell.textLabel.text = @"First";
        }else{
            cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", indexPath.row];
      }
      return cell;
    }
```

What I need to do is:

Change `numberOfRowsInSection()` to return 11, and then change code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath()` to set `cell.textLabel = @"Top Spot";` if row is 10.

Then I want to move "Top Spot" to the top of `UITableView` list before "First" as if "Top Spot" has always been row 0 and "First" has always been row 1. I can't do it that way in the controller since it's already out in the app store and an update would have users reporting wrong values for existing records. So as far as the rest of the app is concerned, "Top Spot" is actually row 10 and only the display of the table knows what's happening. User's that select "Top Spot" would actually be selecting row 10, and not row 0.

Is this possible?

Thanks for any input.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. You might be able to make it work by making what looks like that first cell (the one with "Top Spot" in it) actually be a table header view.

Comment: Do you want Top spot to be selected?. Or is is just a dummy Cell

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I want "Top Spot" To behave like a normal cell. As far as the controller is concerned, it thinks "Top Spot" is actually at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store Your data into a NSArray or 
NSMutableArray then arrange it to any order that you want 
and display data from Array or Dictionary.it would be arranged one

Another approach you can do is you can create a Custom class and can store a specific property to it

say

```
 @interface exampleClassName :NSObject 
{
 @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * ex1;
 @ property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * ex2;
 @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * ex3;
 @property (nonatomic) NSInteger arrange;

}
```

*then your .m implementation file according to your need.
Here it the read trick for you. Now you create Object of this class and can start storing objects into an array

```
 exampleClassName *ex1=[exampleClassName alloc] init];
  ex1.arrange=1;
  ex1.ex1=@" ";
 ex1.ex2=@" ";
 ex1.ex3=@" ";

  NSMutableArray *array=[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:ex1,........];
```

Now you can arrange this NSMutable Array Based upon Object     "arrange"  property which is an integer you can give value to this arrange property based upon your specific priority.say you want to display  "Top Spot" at the top you can give it its arrange property value 1 based upon Ascending or Decending arrangements.

Hope this can help you.